# The procedure entry point _ZdlPvj could not be located in the dll ${pathToDir}\demoGame.exe

Tags: c++, windows, sdl, sdl-2

I am attempting to set up SDL2 for creating a C++ game for windows. When I run the below make file with just a single source file, I get no errors, and the program can run. When I attempt to run the make file with multiple source files, the compilation goes smoothly, but when I attempt to run the program, i get the error seen in the title. It appears to only happen when I attempt to create an instance of a class in the second source file, and try to access either members or instance functions.

I have tried redownloading and setting up my environment, updating mingw (didnt hurt to try) and triple checking my code. I have included the makefile, as well as the source files I am using. Thank you for any help.

EDIT: It seems that the delete call in the main function causes this error... Not sure if that is a coincidence or if the cause does lie somewhere there...

```
#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project
OBJS = src/*.cpp src/*.hpp

#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

#INCLUDE_PATHS specifies the additional include paths we'll need
INCLUDE_PATHS = -Iinclude/SDL2

#LIBRARY_PATHS specifies the additional library paths we'll need
LIBRARY_PATHS = -Llib

#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
# -Wl,-subsystem,windows gets rid of the console window
COMPILER_FLAGS = 

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

#OBJ_NAME specifies the name of our exectuable
OBJ_NAME = demoGame

#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "grid.hpp"
#include <iostream>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    Grid* grid = new Grid(1, 2);

    // These two lines seem to cause an issue.
    std::cout << grid->getRows() << std::endl;
    delete grid;


    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

```
class Grid {
public:
    Grid(int rows, int columns) {
        this->rows = rows;
        this->columns = columns;
    }

    int getRows() {
        return this->rows;
    }

private:
    int rows;
    int columns;
};
```

Comment: I *think* it happens because your game picks up incorrect versions of `.dll`s it depends on, from some random locations in your `PATH`. Copy `SDL2.dll` to the directory where your `.exe` is. Additionally, from `/bin` directory of your compiler, copy `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, `libwinpthread-1.dll` (the names can be slightly different depending on your MinGW distribution).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you so much, that seems to have fixed it !! :)